# Get output from SQL $rows pull into JSON without quotes around array

Tags: php, sql, json

I am using the Populate.js by Dave Stewart. In his example for populating checkboxes he wants the json to look like the following:

```
$('#form-complex).populate({
'name':'Dave Stewart',
'country':['scotland','ireland'],
'contact':['email','phone']
})
```

When we spit ours out using php we get:

```
$('#form-complex).populate({
'name':'Dave Stewart',
'country':'['scotland','ireland']',
'contact':'['email','phone']'
})
```

The quotes around the arrays are killing us. We are generating our json in php using this script after opening a table

```
     while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
      {
         $data = $row; 
      }
     echo json_encode($data);
```

What do we need to do in order to get the arrays to not be treated like text and therefore have quotes around them? We are currently saving them as nvarchars in the table. Do I need to save them as something different? Thanks.

Comment: if that's all you have for your php, then your "arrays" are actually json that was stored in the db,s o you're doing json-in-json, which doesn't work. You've to json_decode() those fields in, embed the new array into your $data array, and THEN encode to json after the db fetch loop completes

Comment: and note that what you have isn't json_encode() output. json uses `"` to quote strings/keynames.

Comment: We have double quotes in our output. I was just simplifying the look based on his tutorial from this page http://davestewart.io/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row);`

Comment: and note, not this problem, but the way you assign $row to $data it will only ever contain the last row.

Comment: ["cosponsor"]=>NULL [76]=> string(12) "['Research','Women']"   <-- Am saving it as  string. Is this the wrong format?